# Javascript/jQuery - Float Validating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, google-maps

I have a textfield that a person can input a price into (XX.xx). Is there a way to make sure they only put in no more than 2 digits after the decimal?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the major types of validation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//for numeric integer only
var num_int_Exp = /^[0-9]+$/;
$("body").on("keypress", ".custom_numeric_int", function(e){
        var keynum;
            if(window.event){ // IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }else
            if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                    keynum = e.which;
            }
            if(!String.fromCharCode(keynum).match(num_int_Exp))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});

//for numeric float only
$("body").on("keypress", ".custom_numeric_float", function(e){
    //$('.custom_numeric_float').keypress(function(event)
        //alert($(this).val().indexOf("."));
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") > -1 && event.which == 46) {
            return false;
        }

        if ((event.which != 46) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});


//for character input
var charExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
$("body").on("keypress", ".custom_char", function(e){
            var keynum;
            if(window.event){ // IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }else
            if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                    keynum = e.which;
            }
            if(!String.fromCharCode(keynum).match(charExp))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});

//for alpha-numeric input
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
$("body").on("keypress", ".custom_alphanumeric", function(e){
            var keynum;
            if(window.event){ // IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }else
            if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                    keynum = e.which;
            }
            if(!String.fromCharCode(keynum).match(alphaExp))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});});
```

Now give the appropriate class to your textbox and you are done with validation.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the input-price issue with a [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). There are more on the [jQuery website.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputmask)

Validating data can be done on format and content. When done on format you can use a [jQuery validate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate). For format I would use a webservice for the adresses, but for State and Country you could provide a dropdown (input-select) with a mandatory selection.

Zipcode e.g differs per country, so you have to make that dependent to the country selection ;)

Answer (score 1):

Code for decimal position:

```
<input type="text" class="price" value="" />

$('.price').keydown(function() {
    var decPos = $(this).val().split('.'); 
    if(decPos.length > 1)
    {
        decPos = decPos[1];
        if(decPos.length >= 2) return false;
    }
});
```

Validating address info would probably found here - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: this does not make sure a decimal is entered as the OP asked.

Comment: It checks the value and does not let a user put more than two decimal places in. Would you like me to add in a jsfiddle.net link to show you how it works?

Comment: what happens if I type in AAA.AA, it works, however this is not a decimal ;)

Comment: Honestly I didn't believe someone would put letters into a price input. If the OP would like, I will edit it to disallow everything except letters and a decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice is using Regular Expressions. [More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

For Decimal examples:

```
var decimal = /\.\d\d$/;
```