# how to mandate a number to display 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that the way to truncate a number to 2 decimal places in `toFixed()`. However, in case the number has just 1 decimal place, I get an error.

What is the way to mandate a number to display >2 decimal places(numbers after the decimals will be 0 in this case) so that `toFixed()` will not throw an error?

Comment: What is the error? I don't know any browser where `toFixed` should be throwing an error in that scenario.

Comment: What error? http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/AbPEz/

Comment: Hm... normally, `toFixed` should add zeros at the end to match the required number of places.  `var num = 10; var result = num.toFixed(2);` should product `10.00`.

Comment: Please post your code... toFixed works as intended for me (e.g.: `a=1.2; a.toFixed(4);` -> returns 1.2000)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895760/javascript-jquery-float-validating

Comment: Kindof odd. `var num = 10; num.toFixed(2);` works, however `10.toFixed(2)` does not. *(testing with google chrome in console)*

Comment: I think the jQuery tag should be removed.  The question doesn't involve it (`toFixed` is plain old Javascript), and I'm betting answers won't require it.  http://jsfiddle.net/umJRt/ - note the "No-Library (pure JS)" on the left.

Comment: `10.toFixed(2)` don't work... but `(10).toFixed(2)` works :]

Comment: Voting to close because I cannot repro the error with the information provided.  The question, as is, is incomplete.  neuDev33, please provide a minimal code sample that repros the problem, and if it is browser specific let us know which browser you're using that is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on any input:

```
var result = Math.round(original*100)/100;
```

Generally, I would avoid using toFixed(), as it can behave unexpectedly when given non float input. Also, see here:

[How to format a float in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

[Trying to format number to 2 decimal places jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407450/trying-to-format-number-to-2-decimal-places-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to apply toFixed on a string ? You could just parse it into a float before using toFixed on it.

```
var a = '1.0'; 
a = parseFloat( a ); 
a = a.toFixed(2); 
console.log( a );
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem was, but I made a few code changes and toFixed works just fine now.